# ReferenceError: Sheet is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When I try to run this code in Google Apps Scripts to export a sheet in a .json I get "ReferenceError: Sheet is not defined in Line 3" I already turn on the Google Sheets API but the outcome its the same

```
function getData(spreadsheetId, sheet){
  var rangeName = sheet+'A:Z';
  var values = Sheet.Spreadsheets.Value.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
  
  if(!values){
    return {error: 'No data found'};
  } else {
   
    var responseJson = [];
    
    for(var row = 1; row < values.lenght; row++){
      var item = {};
      
      for(var column = 0; column < 100; column++){
        item[values[0].column] = values[row][column];      
      }
      responseJson.push(item);
    }
    return responseJson;
  }
}

function doGet(request) {
  if (request.parameter.spreadsheetId != undefined && request.parameter.sheet != undefined){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(getData(request.parameter.spreadsheetId, request.parameter.sheet)));
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({error: "Parameter spreadsheetId or sheet nor found"}));
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to Resources menu inside Script Editor, Advanced Google Services and turn on Sheets service. You should also rename "Sheet" to "Sheets".

[image]

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, it worked c,: ...  Now I have another problem but that doesn't matter, for now, I was stuck with that error for so much, I can't express how grateful I am

Comment: @JhonatanBeltrán If the given answer resolved your issue, consider accepting it as an answer.